# Enviar y Recibir datos entre archivos .py

Tags: python

Estoy comenzando a estudiar Python y tengo la siguiente duda, quizas porque estoy acostumbrado a php y con Python se hace de una forma diferente, quiero enviar y recibir datos de un archivo .PY a otro.

archivo ENVIAR.PY

```
import requests
datos = {"nombre":"Nodgard"}
respuesta = requests.post("recibe.py",data=datos)
print respuesta.text
```

archivo RECIBE.PY

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print form
```

En el archivo Enviar.py me da el siguiente error: Invalid URL 'recibe.py', es porque requests solo permite interactuar con direcciones web? como podria hacerlo con archivos .py que esten localmente?

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer no es tan fácil como parece. La parte del envío podría ser un simple script en Python pero la parte de la recepción tendría que ser algún tipo de web service que puedas consumir o en su defecto una aplicación de intercambio de archivos tipo P2P (peer to peer).

Comment: No termino de entender lo que pretendes con esto, normalmente un script CGI es invocado desde un servidor HTTP. ¿Que es lo que pretendes hacer con esto y con qué finalidad?

Comment: En php puedo intercambiar datos entre archivos .php, esto no funciona de la misma manera con Python? indiferentemente de la funcionalidad que le valla a dar pienso que esto deberia ser posible y no deberia ser tan complejo

Comment: No se si te refieres a algo como PHP Sessions. Si es eso ten en cuenta que Python no está enfocado al desarrollo web como PHP. Las sesiones son un concepto Web y en Python (y en la mayoría de los casos de programación general) poner cosas en el ámbito global no es muy recomendable ni seguro. Si necesitas algo somo Sessions para Web cualquier framework te lo permitirá (django, Flask, CherryPy, etc). En aplicaciones generales puedes comunicar dos programas Python mediante múltiples métodos: sockets, IPC, Posix, DBUS, pipes, serializacion (pickle/cpickle), bases de datos, mmap, multiprocess etc

Comment: Bueno seguire investigando pero lo que me dices tiene logica, he programado por 5 años en php y me he acostumbrado a la programacion enfocada a la WEB, quiero aprender Python porque tengo entendido que es un lenguaje que puede utilizarse tanto para Web como para aplicaciones de escritorio. Mil gracias de antemano. @FJSevilla, hablaba de comunicar 2 archivos .PY porque tenia curiosidad de si podria programar un Webservice hecho en Python y consumirlo mediante otros archivos .Py

Answer (score 2):

luego de leer y releer creo que lo que necesitas son sockets

**ENVIAR**

```
# ENVIAR.py" 
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*
import socket              
# Creamos un objeto de clase socket 
s = socket.socket()
# Indicamos el host y el puerto que estar a la escucha con una tupla 
s.bind(("localhost", 9999))
# Metodo listen para aceptar conexiones entrantes # con el numero maximo de conexiones aceptadas 
s.listen(1) 
# Metodo accept para escuchar # Bloquea la ejecucion hasta que llega un mensaje # Cuando este llega, devuelve un objeto socket # y una tupla con el host y el puerto de la conexion 
c, addr_socketc = s.accept() 

print("Conexion desde", addr_socketc)

# Esperamos un mensaje del cliente 
recibido = c.recv(1024) 
print(recibido.decode("utf-8"))
# Cerramos los sockets
c.close()
s.close()
```

**RECIBIR**

```
# "RECIBE.py" 
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*
import socket
# Creamos un objeto clase socket 
s = socket.socket()
# Intentamos conectar con un puerto de un host 
s.connect(("localhost", 9999))
# Enviamos un mensaje al servidor 

s.send(bytes("mensaje del cliente", "utf-8"))

# Cerramos el socket s.close()
```

OBVIAMENTE hay mucha tela para cortar hablando de sockets ya que para un buen funcionamiento deben juntarse con threads y otras cosas...

un buen ejemplo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOhGkuCUh6w